# How to understand the type of a request?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect Ajax calling URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124636/detect-ajax-calling-url)

is it possible to understand if a request is sent using ajax(xhr) from a server side language like php? I should know if the request is sent from a "normal page" or from an ajax call... is it possible without passing arguments(querysring) to the .php page?

Answer (score 0):

By setting setRequestHeader method so the server will know that the data youre sending and you could set content type in that.