# PHP and AJAX function to return or echo based on call

Tags: php, ajax, backbone.js, crud

I'm writing a function that will return database results.

I need it to `return` the data if the function is called from another function and `echo` the data when its called via AJAX.

**Possible Solutions**

- Pass in a parameter...`if($echo) echo $data; else return $data;`
- Separate functions...`function employees_ajax() { echo $this->employees(); }`

I'd prefer something smarter that can detect that 'itself' was called from another function and `return` instead of `echo`.

**UPDATE**

Another possibility would be to check the  $_SERVER variable.

*"As far as I know, the X-Requested-With is sent by the Ajax functions of most major Frameworks but not all...it's safe to say it's not generally a 100% reliable method to determine whether a request is an AJAX request or not."*

[Does $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] exist in PHP or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579254/php-does-serverhttp-x-requested-with-exist-or-not)

It would be fail-safe to rely on the server rather than the client / js framework.

**UPDATE 2: RESULT**

```
function employees($id = NULL, $return = FALSE) {

    .
    .
    .
    if($return === TRUE) return json_encode($data);
    else echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124636/detect-ajax-calling-url

Comment: I don't think it is a good approach. You should process the return on the calling php.

Comment: What kind of data does `employees()` return? Are you wanting to return JSON if it's AJAX and a PHP array otherwise?

Comment: @woz `employees()` should return a JSON string for both scenarios...`return json_encode($data);` or `echo json_encode($data);`.

Comment: What do you do with the JSON when the function is called by PHP?

Comment: @woz It bootstraps the data: `<script> var employees = <?php echo $employees ?></script>` http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap

Comment: When would you use `return` inside `employees()` then? If you call a function via AJAX and do a `return`, you won't get the JSON data.

Comment: @woz Yes. When my other PHP function calls `employees()` it should `return` the JSON string to bootstrap it into the page. When the AJAX calls `employees()` it needs to `echo` the JSON string (Note paragraph 2 of the original question above). So I need to find a way for `employees()` to distinguish between AJAX calls and calls from other functions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12407/discussion-between-woz-and-flackend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving your `employees` function an optional flag:

```
function employees ($shouldEchoResult = true) {

  if ($shouldEchoResult) {
    echo $result;
  }
  else {
    return $result;
  }

}
```

If it's called with AJAX, don't set the flag. Otherwise, in your code, use `categories(false)`. That's the only other solution I can think of. PHP doesn't have anything built in for that like Ruby does.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, "A PHP Error was encountered" error will be thrown, because, you are getting undefined key in `$_SERVER` superglobal.

First of all, create function that determine if query was from XMLHttpRequest.

```
/**
 * 
 * @return BOOl, true if ajax, false if regular way
 */
function is_ajax(){
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']);
}
```

Then, depending on `is_ajax()` result, you should implement another function that represent key => val pairs from your SQL server.